# Trying to connect S3 bucket to lambda function resulting in 'BadZipFile' error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I originally found the solution seen below here ([How to zip files on s3 using lambda and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065587/how-to-zip-files-on-s3-using-lambda-and-python)) but it's not working for me. I keep getting a 'BadZipFile' "file is not a zipfile" error on the line where I have zipfile.ZipFile(buffer), indicating to me that buffer isn't formatted correctly to be passed in as an argument. If it makes any difference, I've tried passing in a .zip file and a .exe file as the key into the s3_resource.Object but neither one worked...not sure how to solve this, thanks!

```
def handler():
    # TODO implement
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name="bucket_name", key=fileObject)
    buffer = io.BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())

    z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer) # error on this line
    for filename in z.namelist():
        file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
        s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
            z.open(filename),
            Bucket='bucket_name',
            Key=fileObject
        )
        
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: There's a reason that code you copied isn't marked as the correct answer to that question. The code is for reading a zip file from S3, which is the opposite of what the question was asking for.

Comment: @MarkB Wait, but just to be clear I'm passing in a .zip file into the key parameter, so shouldn't this still work?

Comment: You actually have a zip file in S3 currently, and you want to unzip it and send all the files it contains to S3? I ask because when you mentioned you tried adding ".zip" and ".exe" it sounded like you were just making stuff up without passing real existing S3 object keys.

Comment: That's correct, S3 -> Unzip -> S3, and when I said .zip and .exe, I mean I uploaded some files from my personal computer into the S3 bucket--one was a .zip file and the other was a .exe file (just to test if using the .zip format was for some reason a problem) Also, for the key name just to be clear, I'm not using the zip file URI, ARN, or Etag, just the name of the uploaded file @MarkB

Comment: Do you get correct value for `fileObject` ?